# Converting Pandas DataFrame structure into Pytorch Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

Have a question regarding Pytorch framework that I started to use recently (while always used keras/tf in the past).

So I would like to convert simple pandas `DataFrame` to the pytorch `Dataset`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

For applying desirable transformation, I create custom Dataset class and inherit from the pytorch Dataset in the following way:

```
from datasets import Dataset

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, src_file):
        df = pd.read_csv(src_file)
        self.A = df['A']
        self.B = df['B']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.A)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        A_py = self.A.iloc[idx]
        B_py = self.B.iloc[idx] 
        return A_py, B_py
```

When I try to execute the code doing:

```
data = CustomDataset('src_file')
data
```

receiving an error of the following kind:

```
AttributeError: 'CustomDataset' object has no attribute '_info'
```

What is wrong here and how should I change my approach?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simple: you're confusing the `datasets` library with PyTorch's `Dataset` class. Your import statement should target PyTorch's dataset-handling facilities, not another library. Ensure you're using `from torch.utils.data import Dataset` to get the correct base class for your custom dataset.

The AttributeError you're facing is because the `datasets` library expects a different structure for dataset objects, including metadata attributes like `_info`, which are irrelevant to your use case. Stick to PyTorch's `Dataset` class, and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in your imports and are currently importing Dataset from another package. This should resolve your error :

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
```